# Run Javascript in Chrome from an external program

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I need to be able to tell an existing Chrome window to execute a line of Javascript, on the current tab, that I specify from another process.  The end goal is to be able to script a webpage that was not designed to be scriptable.  **How can I run arbitrary Javascript from another program as if it was typed into the developer console?**

Ideally, I would like to use a Bash command or similar, but if there's another way, I'm open to that as well.  If it matters, I'm running macOS.

Comment: I'm not certain exactly what you're after, but would a script injector work for you? e.g. on page load a script automatically gets added to the page and run. For Chrome I use TamperMonkey.

Comment: That won't quite work, because I need a way to invoke the injection on-demand.  But that is a good idea, maybe I can re-think the application.

Comment: You could always inject a script that polls a server for commands, though obviously that's a rather nasty settup. Could be plausible if you have no other options though.

Answer (score 0):

The most widely-accepted way to do this is to use [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) WebDriver, which provides APIs in basically every mainstream language to be able to script Firefox, Chrome, and Edge.

For example, in Python:

```py
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

Does what you'd expect.